# R Variable scoping issue of parallel calculation (%dofuture%) in a nested function

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing, scope

I have a variable scoping issue when I try to do the parallel calculation using `%dofuture%` in a nested function.

Here is the error message I get:

> Error in eval(quote({ : object 'opt' not found

Here is my code (object `opt` is substituted by `local_var1`):

```
myFunction1 = function(x){
  
  y = x + 1
  return(y)
}
```

```
myFunction2 = function(x, y){
  
  z = x + y
  return(z)
}
```

```
myFunction3 = function(function_var4, function_var5, function_var6){
  
  # Claim some local variables
  local_var1 = vector("list", length = ncol(function_var4))
  local_var2 = vector("list", length = ncol(function_var4))
  local_var3 = function_var5 %>% pull(function_var6)
  local_var4 = data.frame(Var = seq(min(local_var3), max(local_var3), length.out = 10000))
  
  # Do some parallel calculation
  plan(multisession, workers = parallel::detectCores() - 2)
  
  foreach (i = 1:ncol(function_var4)) %dofuture% {
    
    data_glm = data.frame(Var = local_var3,
                          PreAbs = function_var4[,i])
    
    mod_glm = glm(PreAbs ~ poly(Var, 3), family = binomial, data = data_glm)
    
    # Result of the calculation
    local_local_var1 = predict(mod_glm, newdata = local_var4, se = F, type = "response")
    
    # Some simple calculation using local_local_var1
    # Save the result
    local_var1[[i]] = mean(local_local_var1)  # <---- I guess this cause the error
    local_var2[[i]] = myFunction1(local_local_var1)    
  }
  
  # Close multisession workers by switching plan
  plan(sequential)
  
  local_var5 =  myFunction2(local_local_var1, function_var5)
  
  return(list(opt = unlist(local_var1),
              nw = unlist(local_var2),
              miv = unlist(local_var5)))
}
```

I get the error message when run the code:

```
library(foreach)
library(doFuture)
library(dplyr)

global_var1 = matrix(sample(c(0, 1), size = 10000, replace = T), ncol = 100) %>%
  as.data.frame()
global_var2 = data.frame(C1 = rnorm(100))
global_var3 = "C1"
  
result = myFunction3(function_var4 = global_var1, function_var5 = global_var2, function_var6 = global_var3)
```

I guess the error is because that `%dofuture%` can get only the variables and settings from global environmental but it can't get the variables and settings from local environment. Is there any possible way to solve the problem?

Comment: You haven't told us which packages you are using, and I suspect what you posted won't generate the error you saw.  You should post a minimal *reproducible* example.

Comment: Hi, here is the reproducible code which got the same error message. (It should be like: Error in eval(quote({ : object 'local_var1' not found)

Comment: Looks like a bug in `doFuture` to me.  The `%dofuture%` operator does record the environment where it was called, and passes it to `doFuture:::doFuture2` which actually does all the work, but somewhere along the line the environment isn't being used.  Henrik Bengtsson (the author of `doFuture`) knows what he is doing, so he could probably fix this if you report it to him.

Comment: Actually, it may be a design flaw in `foreach` that `doFuture` has no way to work around.

Comment: Is it possible for me to define a custom environment and assign it as the default environment when doing the parallel calculation? Besides, how I can report the bug to the author?

Comment: I have posted some suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a bug in `doFuture`. The `%dofuture%` operator does record the environment where it was called, and passes it to `doFuture:::doFuture2` which actually does all the work, but somewhere along the line the environment isn't being used. Henrik Bengtsson (the author of `doFuture`) knows what he is doing, so he could possibly fix this if you report it to him as an "issue" at https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/doFuture/issues.  However, it may be a design flaw in `foreach` that `doFuture` has no way to work around.

Edited to add a new method:

I managed to construct a workaround, and here's a way to run the code without the error message you saw, and to obtain the results.  Change your `myFunction3` by putting the
code executed in the `foreach` loop into a local function.  Instead of trying to save results by assignment to your local variables, return them from the function, and process them afterwards.  Here's code to do those things:

```r
library(foreach)
library(doFuture)
library(dplyr)

myFunction1 = function(x){
  
  y = x + 1
  return(y)
}

myFunction2 = function(x, y){
  
  z = x + y
  return(z)
}

myFunction3 = function(function_var4, function_var5, function_var6){
  
  # Claim some local variables
  local_var1 = vector("list", length = ncol(function_var4))
  local_var2 = vector("list", length = ncol(function_var4))
  local_var3 = function_var5 %>% pull(function_var6)
  local_var4 = data.frame(Var = seq(min(local_var3), max(local_var3), length.out = 10000))
  
  # Do some parallel calculation
  plan(multisession, workers = parallel::detectCores() - 2)
  
  loopcode <- function(i) {
    
    data_glm = data.frame(Var = local_var3,
                          PreAbs = function_var4[,i])
    
    mod_glm = glm(PreAbs ~ poly(Var, 3), family = binomial, data = data_glm)
    
    # Result of the calculation
    local_local_var1 <- predict(mod_glm, newdata = local_var4, se = F, type = "response")
    
    # Some simple calculation using local_local_var1
    # Return the result
    list(return_var1 = mean(local_local_var1), 
         return_var2 = myFunction1(local_local_var1),
         return_local = local_local_var1)    
  }
  
  res <- foreach (i = 1:ncol(function_var4)) %dofuture% loopcode(i)
  
  # Close multisession workers by switching plan
  plan(sequential)

  # Use the final value of local_local_var1
  local_var5 =  myFunction2(res[[ncol(function_var4)]]$return_local, function_var5)

  # Extract all values of the others
  local_var1 <- lapply(res, function(x) x$return_var1)
  local_var2 <- lapply(res, function(x) x$return_var2)
  
  return(list(opt = unlist(local_var1),
              nw = unlist(local_var2),
              miv = unlist(local_var5)))
}


global_var1 = matrix(sample(c(0, 1), size = 10000, replace = T), ncol = 4) %>%
  as.data.frame()
global_var2 = data.frame(C1 = rnorm(100))
global_var3 = "C1"

result = myFunction3(function_var4 = global_var1, function_var5 = global_var2, function_var6 = global_var3)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for all the exploring. I'll try to report the issue~